# How to change who a Pull Request is assigned to

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

I want to change who is assigned to a pull request.  I created the pull request, but I want to change it to someone else.  Can I do that in Azure DevOps?

[image]

Comment: I don't think that is the assigned to.  I believe it is the created by.  If you want input from others on the PR, you can add them as reviewers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user you've circled in your screenshot is the user who has **submitted** the pull request, not who it is **assigned to**. You cannot change who the pull request submitter is once the request has been created.

In this instance, what you're referring to (who the pull request is "assigned to,") is called a reviewer. Reviewers are tasked with [looking over the proposed code changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=azure-devops#browse-code-changes), leaving [feedback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=azure-devops#leave-comments) on the pull request, and [voting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=azure-devops#vote-on-the-changes) on whether or not the pull request should be completed.

You can assign or unassign reviewers to a pull request in a couple different ways.

1. When opening a pull request, you can add reviewers by inputting project members' usernames via the "Reviewers" textbox. You can add *required* reviewers (i.e. the PR will require their review before completing) by clicking the "Add Required Reviewers" button. Here's what that textbox looks like on the page that appears when you attempt to create a new pull request:

> [image: Image of the reviewers textbox]

2. On an existing pull request, you can click the "Add" dropdown and select the type of reviewer you want to add (optional or required) and in the textbox that's focused when you make your selection, type in the name of the project contributor you wish to add. Here's what that "Add" dropdown looks like:

> [image: Existing pull request "add" button for adding a new reviewer]

This info is also more expansively explained in the [Microsoft PR documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=azure-devops#add-and-remove-reviewers).

Your project's administrators can also set up policies to [automatically assign reviewers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#automatically-include-code-reviewers) to pull requests on a branch-by-branch basis when editing that branch's policies. The section to adjust is "Automatically included reviewers".

Comment: The problem with this is that all changes once they are approved and merged to master will go under the name of the creator (if squash is used). Therefore, the name of a person who potentially did 95% of the work on the PR and who was handed over the PR shortly after the PR creation will be hidden in git history.

Comment: @gzsun if you care about the name don't do squashes. I have yet to meet anyone who directly consider squashes good practice. At most it is seen as an improvement over people who don't care about learning git but still use it...